# Problems uploading a file in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a simple program to upload and display the contents of a .csv file in Shiny. I copy-pasted the file upload example from the shiny website but it did not work. The output table simply displays "X.object.Object." and I get warnings:

```
Warning in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on     '/var/folders/2d/2vmslzld48xf_y40rjg3sry00000gp/T//RtmpRLx4Va/aa2cf08f688d80f5d1fd5209/0'
Warning in matrix(align.tmp[(2 - pos):(ncol(x) + 1)], nrow = nrow(x), ncol = ncol(x) +  :
  data length exceeds size of matrix
```

I made some extra elements to display the file object from the Shiny file upload input, and the result of file.info on the file path given by it. The Shiny input object looks fine (detects the file type and size correctly), but file.info says it is only 15 bytes long when it should be several kb. Using readChar to get the file's contents as a simple string also does not work. Reading the file in with read.csv or readChar from the console works fine. I am thinking that it is somehow not saving the file correctly when it is uploaded. How can I check this?

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                 'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                   '"')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('contents'),
      tableOutput('stuff1'),
      tableOutput('stuff2'),
      textOutput('moreStuff')
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
# By default, the file size limit is 5MB. It can be changed by
# setting this option. Here we'll raise limit to 9MB.
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 10*1024^2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  })

  output$stuff1 <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    file.info(inFile$datapath)[c("size", "isdir", "mode", "uid", "gid", "uname", "grname")]
  })

  output$stuff2 <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    as.data.frame(inFile)
  })

  output$moreStuff <- renderText({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    readChar(inFile$datapath, inFile$size)
  })
})
```

Comment: This code worked just fine for me. I tested with Chrome 35.0.1916.153 and shiny_0.10.0 using R version 3.1.0.

Comment: Tested on another computer, works fine. Uninstalled R on the original computer, reinstalled version 3.1.0 and shiny 0.10.0, still have the same problem.

Comment: What OS? What browser?