# Locale error while deploying in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the same problem as asked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687358/problems-uploading-a-file-in-shiny). The problem wasn't solved so I decided to ask about the same question again here (I don't know if this is the way to do it or if a comment in the original question would have been more appropriate).

I have made a Shiny application and get the following error while deploying:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading application bundle...Detecting system locale ... Error in 
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'system("systeminfo /FO csv", 
intern = TRUE, wait = TRUE)'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... systemLocale -> systemInfo -> read.csv -> read.table
Execution halted
```

I have to tried to change my locale by this piece of code but the problem persists:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```